# What signals are expected on the connectors for this 12V Volkswagen Scirroco wiper motor circuit

Tags: motors, automotive-engineering, circuits, circuit-design

[image: possibly the unit]

EDIT: added a picture of a very similar unit.

[image: Code on motor]I picked up a used VW rear? wiper motor that I want to use for a simple motion experiment.

Having no idea how to power the thing I popped open the case and looked inside.

Not really wanting to break it (and not being extremely motor savvy) I am asking if my assumptions are correct.

A) The large ground looking plane on the left side of the board is likely ground
B) The voltage is likely 12V or less.  Some of these components look a bit tiny for 12v though?

This is just an exercise in guesswork that may or may not fit into the meta of this beta site but it seemed a good place to ask sensible questions about the circuit.

I did try to find the docs for the part but had no joy.
Appreciate any help. I have a limited current power source that I can test out any guesses with.
Thanks.

[image: guesses and some details]

I am also assuming that the various connections could be i) common ground ii) slow speed iii) fast speed iiii) common +ve

I have no idea if that is correct of the likely order based on the diagram. would also appreciate any insight on those assumptions.

Noting the possible current limiting resistors on two of the channels might this indicate they are the loom switching pins? The center ones?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109104/discussion-on-question-by-twobob-what-signals-are-expected-on-the-connectors-for).

Comment: I update the question with an answer with everything that was discussed in the chat. I would suggest that you clean up the question improve the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

As indicted in the comments usually the VDC for traditional automotive is 12 VDC nominal, though in most cases it is 14 VDC.

Looks like the below image is from a similar configuration. If the part number for the 6 PIN TSOP can be identified this could help get closer to your goal.

[image]

Other observations, this 98-0344 motor driver on the board has a dot over the number 9. This might be indication that the motor driver is damaged.

[image]

Below is some evidence that the motor driver might be shot.

[image]

From the below image it appears that the motor driver was manufactured by International Rectifier (Now Infineon) for NAGARES

[image]

Additionally from [2007 Audi A6 Avant Rear Wiper Motor Repair](http://www.matthewvaras.com/2014/03/14/2007-audi-a6-avant-rear-wiper-motor-repair/)

> The wiper motor is operated on a CANBUS line, so there is an internal PCB that controls the behavior of the wiper arm. The intermittent failures and sporadic operation led me to believe that there was an internal water leak that was shorting out the PCB.

One comment, if this controlled by CANBUS, a transceiver is required together with a microcontroller. Since 98-0344 appears to be motor driver, it might good check if there is components in the other side of the PCB.

With regard to the functioning of wiper motor check out [Dead Things Vlog - Windshield Wiper Motor Wiring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEzOHIGppX4)

Looks like motor driver [Infineon IRS2334SPbF](https://americas.rsdelivers.com/product/infineon/irs2334spbf/infineon-irs2334spbf-triple-high-and-low-side/7848981?cm_mmc=US-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-DA%20%7C%20Smart%20Shopping-_-All%20Products-_-&matchtype=&pla-306310554666&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIw6Lxtsr86QIVCIiGCh1lZQQiEAQYAyABEgLz5vD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) might similar to the one on the PCB

Finally this motor driver is used in other European automotive makes and models such as AUDI A6, thus consider expanding the search.

References:

- [MAHLE moves into vehicle electronics](https://www.mahle.com/en/news-and-press/press-releases/mahle-moves-into-vehicle-electronics-48960)
- [What would be a sensible place to start when blindly powering this wiper unit?](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/what-would-be-a-sensible-place-to-start-when-blindly-powering-this-wiper-unit/)